# JavaScript dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code (html,js,jquery) snippet (http://jsfiddle.net/MUScJ/2/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someFunc(){
    html = '';
    z = 1;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        html += '<input type="button" value="Button_'+z+'"' +
                'onclick="otherFunc(z);">';
         z++;
    }

    $("#container").html(html);

   return true;
}

function otherFunc(z){
    alert('z:' + z);

     return true;   
}

</script>   

<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="someFunc();" />
```

This script outputs five buttons with onclick event. JS function `otherFunc` always returns z variable equal to 6. Is it possible to overcome this ? I want every button have its specific z value - 1,2,3.. and etc.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated demo - http://jsfiddle.net/MUScJ/4/

Updated code -

```
    html += '<input type="button" value="Button_'+z+'"' +
            'onclick="otherFunc('+z+');">';
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using string instead of param :)
This is your updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MUScJ/3/).

But try to replace onclick by jquery bind. Onclick is strongly not recommended for usage :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not use `var`, your `z` variable is global. This is bad news for many reasons. But in your case, your onclick is calling `otherFunc(z)`, where `z` is the global z which gets its final value of 6.

One possible fix is to change the html you generate:

```
var z = 1;
var html = '';
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    html += '<input type="button" value="Button_'+z+'"' +
            'onclick="otherFunc(' + z + ');">';
     z++;
}
```

This is the simplest way to fix it, however you're not really taking advantage of the power that jQuery gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change this:

```
html += '<input type="button" value="Button_'+z+'"' +
    'onclick="otherFunc(z);">';
```

into this:

```
html += '<input type="button" value="Button_' + z + '"' +
    'onclick="otherFunc(' + z + ');">';
```

This issue is a result of the fact you iterate by incrementing `z`, but create code that uses `z` (whatever the value will be when invoked after creation - in this case it is `6`) instead of using `z` to create static code (entering the value in the time of HTML creation).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunc(){
    html = '';
    z = 1;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        html += '<input type="button" value="Button_'+z+'"' +
                'onclick="otherFunc(z);">';
         z++;
    }

    $("#container").html(html);

   return true;
}


function otherFunc(z) {
    return function() {
        alert('z:' + z);
    };
}

</script>    

<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="someFunc();" />
```