# dynamically generated js buttons with closures to assign onclick function parameters

Tags: javascript, dom, closures

I am running into a problem people have posted before: [JavaScript dynamic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041291/javascript-dynamic-parameters)

But my code uses nodes rather than innerHTML assignments, so the existing SO post doesn't seem to apply to my code.

I want to dynamically generate HTML buttons in a table. For each button, I want to call a function with parameters that depend on the button's index/position in the table. First I tried just using lambda functions with the variable over which I was incrementing. This didn't work, so I also tried dynamically named variables, meaning each button should be passing a differently named variable to deal with lazy-loading effects. But this didn't work either. You can see both versions of what I tried in the code below:

This code I paste below is in a for-loop. In the following, I increase i by 1 each time. offset and jj are unchanged within the loop.

```
var variableDynamic = i.toString();
window['variableName' + variableDynamic] = i + offset;

upvote.onclick = function() {
    upVoteA(i + offset, jj);
    //upVoteA(window['variableName' + variableDynamic] , jj);
};
upvote.innerHTML = "Upvote"
```

Someone told me to look into closures, so following this recommendation: http://www.usepatterns.com/blog/javascript-closures I rewrote the onclick function declaration as:

```
upvote.onclick = function() {
    var a = i + offset;
    var b = kk;
    function closeIt(){
        upVoteA(a,b);
    }
    closeIt();
};
```

This still has the same effect that every button calls upVoteA with the same parameter, namely the last/highest value.

I realize I could refactor my code to turn these into .innerHTML set statements and then I'd print the variable and it would be set as a printed statement instead of a lazily-loaded variable. But I'd like not to do that if possible. (apologies that it's not technically lazy loading, the name seems reasonably apt)

Is there a way to make my code work? And why are the closures failing? I thought closures should preserve the environment they were created in, but that is not the case with my code. Which portion of the "environment" are preserved with closures?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad answer, but it works

```
     var funcStr = "function dummy() { upVoteA(" + (i + offset) + "," + jj + "); }";
     eval(funcStr);
     upvote.onclick = dummy;
```

But if  you have something better, please let me know.